# Need help building command classes for a command line interface in java

Tags: java, command, command-line-interface

Ok I am building this spreadsheet application, which I am implementing through a command line interface, where I have certain commands, for instance exit, which terminates the program.

So I have this application class, where I have these fields:

```
private ArrayList<Spreadsheet> spreadsheets;
private Spreadsheet worksheet;
```

and this method:

```
public void newSpreadsheet() {
  worksheet = new Spreadsheet();
  spreadsheets.add(worksheet);
}
```

Then I have this CommandIntepreter class which looks like this:

```
package ui;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import ui.command.Command;
import ui.command.ExitCommand;
import ui.command.FailedCommand;
import ui.command.PrintCommand;
import ui.command.NewCommand;
import ui.command.ListCommand;
import ui.command.ChangeCommand;
import ui.command.SetCommand;
import ui.command.GetCommand;



import spreadsheet.*;
import spreadsheet.arithmetic.*;

public final class CommandInterpreter {

private CommandInterpreter() {
// The class should not be instanciated.
}

public static Command interpret(final Scanner scanner) {
final String keyword = scanner.next();
switch(keyword) {
  case "exit":
    return new ExitCommand();
  case "pws":
    return new PrintCommand();
  case "ns":
    return new NewCommand();
  case "ls":
    return new ListCommand();
  case "cws":
    return new ChangeCommand();
  case "set":
    return new SetCommand();
  case "get":
    return new GetCommand();

}
return new FailedCommand(
  String.format("Illegal start of command, \"%s\".", keyword));
}

}
```

And then I have created the NewCommand class which looks like this:

```
package ui.command;

import spreadsheet.Application;
import spreadsheet.Spreadsheet;

public final class NewCommand
 extends Command {

public void execute() {
 Application.instance.newSpreadsheet();
}
}
```

Which when I write ns should make a new spreadsheet. But when I do this nothing really happens, so might you be able to tell me why that is?

Comment: Your problem description is probably too vague for anyone to really tell what's wrong. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) will get you concise answers.

Comment: Do you save you spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the NewCommand class execute method in order to create the new spreadsheet. I don't see anywhere in your code you did that.

Before this,I believe your are trying to use Command Pattern in this application. I suggest you to create a interface named 'Command'  and with a method 'execute()', then implement the Command interface in all your classes. If you find the 'ns' as command-line input just  create instance for New Command as

```
case "ns":
Command nsCommand = new NewCommand();
nsCOmmand.execute();
return "SOME_MESSAGE"
```

Comment: Could I perhaps ask you to give me an example of how to do that? :)